# Multiple MIME types in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types

Is there a way to use `intent.setType()` and supply multiple broad types (like images *and* video)?

I am using an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. It seems to be working with just comma-separated types.

Comment: Could you be more specific. setType() on...what? For what use and purpose? Etc.

Comment: Have you found out a way to do this yet?

Answer (score 142):

In Android 4.4 when using the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) you can use the [`EXTRA_MIME_TYPES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_MIME_TYPES) to pass multiple mime types.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "video/*"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN);
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Android 7.0. Only shows videos.

Comment: @clocksmith It seems to work fine on my Nexus 9 with Android 7.0.

Comment: @clocksmith Seems to work fine on Android 7.0 emulator as well. Is there a specific case that doesn't work? It seems like this is the right answer since it is part of the official API.

Comment: Work perfectly. The Android way of filtering files types.

Comment: Note that `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES` doesn't replace `setType`. You still need `setType` with this approach.

Comment: How do you do this for Jellybean and bellow?

Comment: Made my day. tks

Comment: It doesn't work when we share content from app to another apps

Answer (score 25):

Actually, multiple mime-types are supported. Have you even tried it???

For example: `intent.setType("image/*,video/*")`  will display photos and videos...

For me it works. It should work for you too...

[EDIT]: This works partially, as not all the gallery apps choose to implement support for multiple mime types filters.

Comment: This solution is working... but only with applications that allows two mime-types. The default one "Gallery" doesn't.

Comment: Actually, it depends on the "Gallery" application you have installed. There are different versions of them being distributed with different android ROMs.

Comment: Works for me in minor cases only. Same images may or may not be selectable. Android 5.0.1

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, this is not currently supported.  You have two options:

(1) Use a MIME type of `*/*` and accept that there may be some things the user can pick that you won't be able to handle (and have a decent recovery path for that); or

(2) Implement your own activity chooser, doing direct calls on the package manager to get the activities that can handle both MIME types for the intent, merging those lists, and displaying them to the user.

Also, `setType()` does not work with comma-separated types at all.  It must be one and only one MIME type.

Comment: Actually, multiple mime-types are supported. Have you even tried it???
For example: image/*,video/*  will display photos and videos...

Comment: @vchelbanster Multiple mimetypes are not supported in all devices. With some android version like < 5.0, it would pick only first mimetype.

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal Partially agree - it's not available for all the apps. Since the app that gets a composite intent type needs to handle multiple mime types for this to work, not all the apps (like gallery app) will work, which might create the impression that it's the OS version that's dependent on. In fact, it's the app's creator that need to handle multiple mime types. So yeah - it's limited support. See my answer.

Comment: @vchelbanster Yup, at first it appeared to me that this is related to OS version. Later I figured out that if your device doesn't have app that handles such type of intents, then the problem will occur.

Answer (score 2):

For me what worked best was:

```
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

You can add several mime types like this

```
intent.setType("image/*|application/pdf|audio/*");
```

But the intent chooser will only display applications that can handle images because it is the first in the mime type string.
However if you have a file manager installed (I tested with the CyanogenMod file manager) you can choose a file that is audio or pdf or an image.

If the audio mime type is the first one, like this:

```
intent.setType("audio/*|image/*|application/pdf");
```

The intent chooser will display only applications that handle audio.
Again using the file manager you can select an image or pdf or audio.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass multiple mime types if you separate with |

```
Intent.setType("application/*|text/*");
```

Answer (score 0):

With `registerForActivityResult()` callback:

```kotlin
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts


class DocumentsFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {

        // 1. List of MIME types
        /**@see <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types">MIME types</a>
         * @see <a href="https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml">IANA - MIME types</a>*/
        private val MIME_TYPES: Array<String> = arrayOf(
            "image/*", "application/pdf", "application/msword",
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
            "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text", "text/plain", "text/markdown"
        )
    }
    
    //2. Register for Activity Result callback as class field
    private val getDocuments =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenMultipleDocuments()/*NOT OpenDocument*/) {
        Log.d("Open documents", "incoming uri: size = ${it.size}")
        add(it)
    }
    
    ...
    //3. set onclick listener
    selectDocumentsButton.setOnClickListener { getDocuments.launch(MIME_TYPES) }
    ...
    
    //4. handle incoming uri list
    private fun add(list: List<Uri>) {
        val setOfFiles = copyToAppDir(list)
        setOfFiles.forEach {
            //TODO: do something            
        }
    }
    
    //5. copy the files to the application folder for further work
    private fun copyToAppDir(list: List<Uri>): Set<File> {
        val set = mutableSetOf<File>()
        list.forEach { uri ->
            try {
                val file: File = copyUriContentToTempFile(uri)
                set.add(file)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        return set
    }
    
    //6. copy selected content by uri
    private fun copyUriContentToTempFile(uri: Uri): File {
        val inputStream = requireContext().contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        inputStream.use { input ->
            val tempFile: File = .. ; //TODO: create file
            tempFile.outputStream().use { output ->
                input?.copyTo(output)
            }
            return tempFile
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

for my work with semicolons.

Example:

```
intent.setType("image/*;video/*")
```

or

```
sIntent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "image/*;video/*");
```

Comment: Instead of the hard-coded "CONTENT_TYPE" string you can use the `Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES` constant. Also instead of semicolons, you can pass an array of strings.