# Intent to select Photo Or Video

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple MIME types in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698050/multiple-mime-types-in-android)

I have a requirement wherein I have to let the user select either a photo or a video.
Can this be done in a single intent?
Currently I am asking user if he wants to select photo or a video and based on his input I set mime type of the intent either "`image/*`" or "`video/*`".

Is there a way to allow user to select photo/video in a single intent?

Thanks,
Yogesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out something like this:

[android-file-dialog](http://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/)

This is allowing following feature too.

> FORMAT_FILTER - files filter. If file name ends with one of filters
>   the file will be displayed.

So, you can specify required filters with this and provide selection of different files to users.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Pick a photo"), requestCode);
```

Haven't tested the result, but the Intent is started correctly (I have tested that)

Comment: Refresh this page, I updated the code a few times

Comment: This code only allows to select images. I wanted both images/videos.
Anyway, looks like it is not possible as mentioned in the link by Dheeraj.

Comment: Yeah I noticed I misread your question. You could do `i.setType("*/*");`, but that'd allow all file types.