# How to open images/videos/audio?

Tags: android

In my application there is a button, that, when pressed, is supposed to open either the picture gallery, or the video gallery, or the audioplayer.

Please how would I construct an intent to perform that?

Comment: do you need OR (any of them) or AND (all of them)?

Comment: @Atul O Holic thanks Atul, AND all of them, so that the user can pick.

Comment: Click on Button you can open ContextMenu and add picture gallery, or the video gallery, or the audioplayer.

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932611/intent-to-select-photo-or-video

Comment: @LisaAnne According to your question i also suggest to you open pop up dialog , Alertdialog or custom dialog and after that perform your actions from it.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA I have already made her that suggestion.

Comment: @LazyNinja I have suggested another with my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this just onclick of any button pass the file path and then this method poen any type of file according to that file

```
 File file = new File(filePath); 
    MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
       String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getName());
         String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
        if (type == null)
        type = "*/*";

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("www.google.com");
    Intent type_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    Uri data = Uri.fromFile(file);
    type_intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
    startActivity(type_intent);
```

For images

```
private void getallimages(File dir)
    {

    String[] STAR = { "*" };
    controller.images.clear();

    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
    Cursor imagecursor = cntx.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, STAR, null, null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    int count = imagecursor.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem();//this is my wrapper class 
        if(new File(imagecursor.getString(imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA))).length()<=10485760)
        {
            imageItem.filePath = imagecursor.getString(imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

        imageItem.id = id;
        imageItem.selection = false; //newly added item will be selected by default this it do for check box unselect u dont need to fill this 
        controller.images.add(imageItem);//this i just add all info in wrapper class    

        }
```

}
     }

for audio

```
private void getallaudio()
{
     String[] STAR = { "*" };
    controller.audioWrapper.clear();
    Cursor audioCursor = cntx.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, STAR, null, null, null);
    if (audioCursor != null) 
    {
        if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) 
        {
            do 
            {

                String path = audioCursor.getString(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));


                           controller.audioWrapper.add(new MediaWrapper(new File(path).getName(), path, "Audio",false));



             }while (audioCursor.moveToNext());

        }
     }


}
```

and for video

```
private void getallvideo()
    {
         String[] STAR = { "*" };

        controller.videoWrapper.clear();
        Cursor videoCursor = cntx.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, STAR, null, null, null);

        if (videoCursor != null) 
        {
            if (videoCursor.moveToFirst()) 
            {
                do 
                {


                    String path = videoCursor.getString(videoCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

                               controller.videoWrapper.add(new MediaWrapper(new File(path).getName(), path, "Video",false,color_string));




                 }while (videoCursor.moveToNext());

            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: thank you Bhanu, but I do not need to open a single file, rather I need the user to see the Gallery and MediaPlayer apps so that he can choose what to use, either audio, video or pictures.

Comment: now see my bigg bigg biggg ans :) it will give u all u want @LisaAnne :)

Answer (score 0):

I would realize it this way:
On Button click, pop up a custom dialog box with 3 buttons.

1. picture gallery button
2. video gallery button
3. audio player button

Depending on user selection, you start the intent which corresponds to the action.

Comment: thank you Lazy Ninja, but unfortunately I need only 1 button. LISA

Comment: @LisaAnne Yes only one button, but you have to add a pop up dialog.