# Files are Unselectable after calling ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I am developing an app, and in this activity a button is pressed and any file can be selected to be uploaded.
The file chooser loads correctly, but all of the images are unselectable (greyed out). I added the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the Manifest file, but I have no idea why it still won't let me choose a file. Here is the code I am using

```
private Button uploadButton;
private TextView uploadFile;
private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;
private String selectedImagePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upload_button);
    uploadFile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uploadFile);

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v){

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("file/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
    }});
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode){
    case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
        if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
            uploadFile.setText(FilePath);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe there are no files with type `"file/*"` have you tried `"*/*"`

Comment: @Blundell intent.setType( "\*/\*") worked for me and the files are not grayed out anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blundell mentioned it in the comment above, but you could also add the below to your manifest file.  Also, try using setType("image/*).

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Blundell's recommendation worked, Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Blundell I face the same problem. but here i read sqlite database (.mdb) file. and even i set the read permission in manifest file, i can't able to select it. but the android mobile having api level-9, it's working fine (able to select). so may i know what's wrong in api level > 9..

Answer (score 15):

Try setting the type to `"*/*"` as suggested by [Blundell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723975/files-are-unselectable-after-calling-action-get-content-intent/31828784#comment43860447_27723975).

If you don't want the user to be able to select content of any type you should log the file's type in onActivityResult ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14300024/1746379) shows how). Then try out a couple of valid files, view the log and modify `intent.setType` accordingly. You can use multiple types on KitKat and above as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23426753/1746379).

Answer (score 3):

When i tried with marshmellow and above the below code helped. I have tried with c#(xamarin). The multiple mime type is the key. Hope this helps someone

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);
            intent.SetType("file/*");
            intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
            String[] mimeTypes = { "text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values" ,"application/pdf","image/*"};
            intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraMimeTypes, mimeTypes);
            ((FormsAppCompatActivity)Forms.Context).StartActivityForResult(intent, 7007);
```

Comment: Neverminding the lower/upper case now. But howcome you first intent.SetType("file/*"); and then intent.SetType("*/*"); 
The second call overwrites the first one which makes it unnecessary.

Comment: +1 thanks :) 
btw I have used your solution as it is the the simplest from above

Answer (score 0):

This code works for opening text (*.txt) files. If you use ACTION_GET_CONTENT, you can also open files from google drive (or other apps that use the intent). If using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, only internal files show up. Other file types are grayed out.

Remember to have appropriate permissions in manifest file.

```
verifyStoragePermissions(ImportExportActivity.this);
String[] mimeTypes = { "text/plain"};
Intent intent = new Intent()
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true)
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
        .setType("file/*")
        //.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a text file"), 123);



private static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
```