# Android.Content.Intent.ExtraMimeTypes Field Not Defined

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.android

I cannot find this for 4.0.3

I peeked the `Intent` class in Visual Studio and it seems every other constant mentioned here **[Android.Content.Intent Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Intent/)** exists except for this one.

I'm attempting to build an "send intent" (`Intent.ActionSend`) for "sharing" a collection of  heterogenous file types selected by user from a `GridView` (mainly pictures and text documents, but could be more in future so want to support the general case now and be done with it).

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot just use "type -- Specifies an explicit type (a MIME type) of the intent data. Normally the type is inferred from the data itself. By setting this attribute, you disable that evaluation and force an explicit type."?

Comment: @YuchenZhong Yeah, I should just try setting it with `setType()`.

Comment: Yay, I am not sure why & where you think there is a `ExtraMimeTypes` property ...

Comment: @YuchenZhong https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_MIME_TYPES

Comment: @YuchenZhong **Fred**'s answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698050/multiple-mime-types-in-android

Comment: @YuchenZhong ... oh on second look it seems this flag was **added in 4.4**. It's just that on Xamarin site it says was **"Add in API Level 1"**, so I was thrown off: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Content.Intent.ExtraMimeTypes/

Comment: Ha, okay. Thanks for sharing that :)

Comment: @YuchenZhong Sure... The docs say that if anything is specified with **`putExtra()`**, then the evaluation of what is specified in **`setType()`** is skipped. I haven't tested this specifically to be sure, but I have found many examples here and elsewhere that use both together.