# Multiple MIME types (for images and pdfs) are not working in RedMI Note (Android 6.0)

Tags: android, android-intent

```
        Inetnt pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        pickIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        String [] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"};
        pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
        pickIntent.setType("application/pdf","image/*");
        pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
```

Here the setType("application/pdf","image/*") and mimeTypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"} both are not working, When I use this code it's opening Device File explorer but not any file in any folder even files are exist.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "are not working" means. What are your symptoms?  Also note that `application/pdf|image/*` is not a valid MIME type.

Comment: Check this link for multiple MIME tyepe in android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698050/multiple-mime-types-in-android

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `import`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Check this sample code for multiple MIME type in android

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Hasnain, but when I use this code intent.setType("*/*"); in device opening file explorer with all type of files and able select all all kind of files.

Comment: Its working code I already tested it at my device its view all device pdf and images. are you facing issue any particular device or on every device

Comment: +1 on Kishore, it shows all files, so the solution is device-dependent and not a general solution (Android 9, Honor view 20, stock apps)

Answer (score 0):

Redmi phones are not recognizing * wild character in "image/*" , So specify file types separately .
i.e :    String[] mimetypes =  {"image/jpeg","image/png","image/exif"} 
and so on