# A problem with Google Photos media intent

Tags: android, google-photos

```
 val mediaIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
 mediaIntent.type = "image/*, video/*"
 startActivityForResult(mediaIntent, REQUEST_MEDIA)
```

When I call this intent Google Photos shows me only images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
val mediaIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
mediaIntent.type = "*/*"
mediaIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf( "video/*","image/*"))
startActivityForResult(mediaIntent, REQUEST_MEDIA)
```

Comment: Its poor solution, because user can pick for example contact or pdf

Comment: Google Photos only accept singe MIME type. If you're ok with not using Google Photos, you can change to different action like: Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. This one is very useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698050/multiple-mime-types-in-android

Comment: shame on Google