# Intent to read both .xls and xlsx files in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, xlsx, xls

My intent picks `.xls` while

```
fileintent.setType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Picks `.xlsx` while

```
fileintent.setType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

How to make both `.xls` and `.xlsx` selectable and readable? Appreciate help!

Comment: .setTypes(); ...  ?

Comment: No, there is no such method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698050/multiple-mime-types-in-android/17867269#17867269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For `.xls` and `.xlsx` extensions,**

Mimetypes are clubbed.

```
Intent intent;
    
        String[] mimetypes =
                { "application/vnd.ms-excel", // .xls
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" // .xlsx
                       };

        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); // or use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

**For other extensions:**

Check the following link, find the corresponding mimetype and include it in the above code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types