# Set Type in Intent to start Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to open Documents and Images both at same time,
I have used SetType method to open Image and PDF, but both of them can't be opened at same time.
Is there any solution to open at same time?
Here I have posted sample code.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setType("application/pdf/*");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple MIME types in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698050/multiple-mime-types-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent .setType("*/*");
String[] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"};
intent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
```

Then define the type based on the returned result.

Comment: Thank You for your concern,
I want only PDF and Images to be open and none other.. ..

Comment: hi@Chanchal Shakti,i updated my code,pls kindly refer.Hope this could help with your issue.

Comment: It works,
I’m so grateful for your help. It was a challenging time but you made it easier. Thank you.